# Where is the code of horizon?

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-horizon

I have installed openstack havana version and the packstack (without neutron). Ok, the dashboard work's fine.

My question is: ¿Where have been installed the source code of horizon?.

I mean, I found source code of dashboard under the `/usr/share/openstack` directory, but I don't know where is the Horizon's code, concretly, source code relative to web pages that is showed on dashboard Website.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I respond my own question.

Horizon is installed at `/usr/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/horizon` directory.

All the other componentes are installed under the `/usr/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/` directory.